# Need help fixing JSON for homebridge plugin

Tags: json

Need help fixing the JSON syntax for a plugin to homebridge. I've been using jsonlint but cannot figure out how to fix the code below so the syntax is correct.

```
{
    "bridge": {
        "name": "Homebridge",
        "username": "xxx",
        "port": 51826,
        "pin": "xxx"
    },
    "accessories": [],
    "platforms": [{
                "name": "Config",
                "port": 8080,
                "auth": "form",
                "log": {
                    "method": "file",
                    "path": "/Users/xx/.homebridge/homebridge.log" ["platform": "config"]
                } {
                    "platform": "DysonPlatform",
                    "name": "DysonPlatform",
                    "email": "xxx",
                    "password": "xxx",
                    "country": "US"
                    "accessories": [{
                            "ip": "xxx",
                            "displayName": "Dyson",
                            "serialNumber": "xxx"
             },
        {
          "ip": "ip of your second device",
          "displayName": "Name to be shown on Home App",
          "serialNumber": "DYSON-XXX-XX-XXXXXXXX-XXX",
          "password": "password of your second device"
              }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Find yourself a JSON linter (hint: Google) and put your JSON through that, then see where it complains. Also, you might want to look into formatting it as something that a human can work with.

Answer (score 0):

Formatted JSON

```
 {
        "bridge": {
            "name": "Homebridge",
            "username": "xxx",
            "port": 51826,
            "pin": "xxx"
        },
        "accessories": [],
        "platforms": [{
                "name": "Config",
                "port": 8080,
                "auth": "form",
                "log": {
                    "method": "file",
                    "path": "/Users/xx/.homebridge/homebridge.log",
                    "platform": "config"
                }
            },
            {
                "platform": "DysonPlatform",
                "name": "DysonPlatform",
                "email": "xxx",
                "password": "xxx",
                "country": "US",
                "accessories": [{
                    "ip": "xxx",
                    "displayName": "Dyson",
                    "serialNumber": "xxx"
                }, {
                    "ip": "ip of your second device",
                    "displayName": "Name to be shown on Home App",
                    "serialNumber": "DYSON-XXX-XX-XXXXXXXX-XXX",
                    "password": "password of your second device"
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
```